# How can I pass an ASP.NET querystring value into my silverlight 2 control?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I have an ASP.NET page.  What I want to do is pass in an ID field that is in the querystring.

So if my page is

http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx?id=35

I want a silverlight control that is on this page to have access to the id field.  My silverlight control is going to get data for a grid and it needs to use the id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this covers the concept in startup parameters (which is possibly what you are doing) here's a walk-through about it. http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=72312

Comment: Tim - that is EXACTLY what I was looking for.  You also show 2 other ways, which I didn't know about.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the HTML DOM Bridge to do that:

```
using System.Windows.Browser;

string queryString = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Query;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the page can prevent you from usign the HTML DOM Bridge if enableHtmlAccess is set to false.